# Uso invertido de palabras cariñosas e insultos

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, español-neutral, vulgaridades

En mi tierra es bastante normal, en el uso coloquial, encontrar invertido el uso de las palabras cariñosas y los insultos:

"Mira, cariño, una cosa te voy a decir..." -dicho a una persona con la que se está teniendo una discusión.

"Hola feo" -dicho a un buen amigo como saludo.

"A ver, guapo, cómo te lo explico..." -dicho a una persona con la que se habla, independientemente de su belleza.

"Y va la muy zorra de mi hermana y me regala el bolso que estuve buscando y no encontraba por ninguna parte" -dicho con evidente cariño a la hermana respectiva.

¿Ustedes saben si esta inversión es generalizada?

Comment: Normalmente en República Dominicana escuchas frases así, pero solamente con personas que tienes confianza o apego.

Comment: En general en el norte de España es muy típico el uso de insultos, incluso graves, para referirse cariñosamente a amigos ("Qué cabrón eres", "Anda hijoputa, ven aquí"). En estos casos el único modo de distinguir entre el uso despectivo o afectivo de la expresión es la entonación que utiliza el hablante. A menudo me sorprender ver gente de otras regiones asustarse por el modo en que nos hablamos, con lo que imagino que no está totalmente generalizado.

Answer (score 4):

Son dos fenómenos bastante interesantes, considerados universales antropológicos y que forman parte de lo que en general llamamos "ironías".

**Eufemismo**: usar palabras inofensivas o expresiones para desorientar, evadir, o evitar hacernos conscientes de una realidad cruda y desagradable.

**Disfemismo**:  es una palabra o expresión deliberadamente despectiva o insultante que se emplea en lugar de otra más neutral.

(Los copié de Wikipedia).

Decir "cariño" a quién se está insultando intensifica el insulto. Es una ironía evidente: tanto el hablante como el oyente entienden que el sentido de la expresión es el contrario del significado de la palabra. Esta es una de las funciones de los eufemismos, aunque hay otras que no son necesariamente irónicas.

Y decirle "feo" a tu amado novio es simplemente, como en la mayoría de los disfemismos, un uso humorístico del lenguaje.

En general los niños aprenden a reconocer e interpretar estas incoherencias semánticas bastante luego. Y aunque su uso aparece en todas las lenguas, hay algunas culturas (como la latina) que las usan en exceso, mientras que en otras aparecen sólo en contextos muy específicos y es preferible no arriesgarse.

Comment: Creo que lo que observas es nada mas que *sarcasmo*, y es ubiquo en todo el mundo, pero especialmente entre amigos cercanos y nunca en ambientes formales.

Comment: Toda la razón, sarcasmo es la palabra precisa. Pero me parece que sí se usa en situaciones formales, como en la oratoria política por ejemplo.

Comment: El término más específico para este tipo de inversión es [antífrasis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2sRbtjU). Lo aprendí respondiendo a [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16993/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-origen-de-la-palabra-menudo/16995#16995)

Comment: Qué interesante. De hecho, la respuesta que das a la otra pregunta es también la respuesta correcta de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

He observado con frecuencia este uso en Colombia, sobre todo el uso de palabras negativas (*feo*) y groseras (*marica<sup>1</sup>, güevón, gonorrea<sup>2</sup>*) como muestra de cariño o camaradería.  A veces, incluso, como simple muletilla.

Menos común, pero también existente es el uso de palabras apreciativas o cariñosas en un sentido desobligante o condescendiente.  También hay personas que usan palabras cariñosas como *mi amor* para referirse a todo el mundo sin que exista una connotación positiva o negativa en ese trato.

<sup>1. ***marica*** conserva básicamente dos significados negativos: 1) forma peyorativa para referirse a los homosexuales, 2) persona de poco carácter (también peyorativo).  Generalmente estos significados usan una pronunciación *normal* de la palabra (tres sílabas cortas fácilmente distinguibles).  Pero, adicional a este uso es común usarlo como forma común y neutral para referirse a amigos sin ninguna implicación sobre la orientación sexual o el carácter.  En este uso la «i» suele alargarse ligeramentre pero no estoy del todo seguro que siempre se haga.  También es usado mucho como muletilla, en cuyo caso las vocales átonas se reducen considerablemente «mric(a)», o como exclamación, en cuyo caso la «i» suele alargarse.  ***güevón*** también tiene una forma reducida para el uso como muletilla, más parecido a «guon» o «huon».</sup>

<sup>2. ***gonorrea***, además del uso neutro como enfermedad de transmisión sexual, es muy usado como insulto.  Creo que este uso es originario de la zona de Antioquia y Medellín, pero ha pasado a un uso extendido en el país a partir de las películas y series sobre el narcotráfico y la cultura *traqueta*.  E. igual que con otros insultos, también es usado entre amigos como fórmula de camaradería.</sup>

Comment: recuerdo los dos años que viví en colombia, me costó acostumbrarme a que las amistades para todo se referian marica esto, marica lo otro(en mi país(Cuba) decirle marica a alguien es un insulto)...y una bronca que vi de una pareja, la mujer le decia al marido gonorrea(lo vi mas genralizado en la zona del valle del cauca)..yo le preguntaba a mi novia si el marido le habia pegado gonorrea

Answer (score 0):

Muy muy común en Cataluña, y diría por toda España en general.

Por otra parte pocas veces escuche mis amigos de Latinoamérica usar estas formas, pero de nunca haber ido allí no te puedo decir si es solo casualidad, o es que realmente no se usan allí.