# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "menudo"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, significado

La palabra "menudo" tiene un sentido equivalente a "what a" en inglés. Por ejemplo, "¡menudo partido!" significa "¡qué gran partido!".

No sé cómo la palabra "menudo" llegó a tener este significado, pues me parece que "menudo" normalmente significa "pequeño", "insignificante".

No encontré una explicación en Google tampoco.

Comment: Parte de la respuesta va por el lado de que en castellano es recurrente usar adjetivos en tono irónico con su sentido opuesto.

Comment: @Rafael exactamente. En algunos lugares de España he oído usar, por ejemplo, _chico marrón me ha caído_ como variante, usando un sinónimo de _menudo_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Menudo, -da** significa pequeño (-a). Proviene del latín, *minutus*, que es al mismo tiempo un adjetivo y el participio del verbo [minuo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dminuo), *disminuir*, *empequeñecer*. En pocas palabras, etimológicamente *menudo* significa *disminuido*, *encogido*.

Su uso en sentido irónico para significar lo contrario (grande) es una forma de ***[antífrasis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2sRbtjU)***:

> Designación de personas o cosas con palabras que signifiquen lo contrario de lo que se debiera decir (DRAE)

Este recurso es muy común en distintos países de habla hispana y también en otros idiomas. De hecho es uno de los mecanismos (aunque está lejos de ser el más común) de cambio léxico-semántico —por los cuales una palabra puede cambiar de significado en el plazo de siglos—. P.ej. la palabra *awful* en inglés, que significa desagradable, a pesar de que *etimológicamente* (*awe*+*ful*) debiera significar *asombroso* o *que inspira respeto*.