# Uso de "gorda" para referirse a las embarazadas en países hispanoparlantes

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

Una de las cosas que más mortificaba a mi mujer durante nuestra última visita a España es el uso de "gorda" para referirse a las embarazadas.

> Oh, qué gorda (o gordita) estás ya. ¿Cuándo decías que salías de cuentas?

Ella, como nativa angloparlante, está acostumbrada al sutil matiz que existe en inglés entre decirle a una persona que es/está `big` y decirle que es/está `fat`. En inglés, nadie (en su sano juicio) le diría a una embarazada

> Oh, you are/ you look **so fat**

sino

> Oh, you are/ you look **so big**

Curiosamente, consultando el DLE

> [**gordo, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JLSh4xE)
>
> 6. adj. coloq. Bol. y Chile. Dicho de una mujer: preñada.

Pero sé por experiencia que eso ocurre en España, no solo en Bolivia y Chile. Parece ser que a pesar de las connotaciones negativas que el adjetivo `gordo` tiene en referencia al aspecto físico, el término pierde cierta connotación peyorativa (o se usa de forma descuidada) al referirse a embarazadas.

Mi pregunta es: ¿es un fenómeno extendido en todos los países hispanoparlantes el referirse a las mujeres embarazadas como "gordas" o decir que están "gordas" (en oposición por ejemplo a decir que están "grandes")?

Comment: En España, desde luego, *¡qué grande estás!* lo usaríamos con niños y sería equivalente a *¡cuánto has crecido!*

Comment: Veo difícil que alguien te pueda responder a la pregunta puesto que requiere conocer biien la cultura de todos los paises hispanoparlantes. En España también se puede decir "¡Qué tripa tienes!". En cualquier caso el término gorda en este contexto no es peyorativo sino más bien al contrario porque tener un hijo ha sido tradicionalmente un riesgo.

Comment: No tiene que ver con la pregunta sobre embarazadas pero *gordo/a* en muchos paises se usa de forma cariñosa para llamar a tu pareja, así que no siempre es peyorativo. En España no se usa de esa forma pero mucha gente llama *gordi* a su pareja.

Comment: En la zona nordeste de España, donde vivo, no he oído nunca este uso de _gorda_ cariñoso para dirigirse a una mujer embarazada. Sí oigo con frecuencia lo que comenta @jalazbe de _¡qué tripa tienes!_.

Comment: Nunca lo oí en vivo y en directo, pero en Argentina se puede llegar a encontrar "estar gruesa" para significar: (pop.) estar embarazada. Según este sitio, proviene del lunfardo: http://www.todotango.com/comunidad/lunfardo/termino.aspx?p=estar+gruesa

Comment: @jalazbe tienes toda la razón. Algunas preguntas de [tag:diferencias-regionales] rozan lo "too broad" y pueden ser difíciles de responder. A veces creamos respuestas _community wiki_ en las que usuarios de distintas regiones dicen "en mi país _esto_ es _así o asá_". En este caso, aunque nadie puede afirmar con seguridad si se cumple o no para _todos_ los países, un "En mi país no" me vale como respuesta, pues quiero saber si acaso el matiz está en el "español neutral". Para distinguir la _mejor respuesta_, habrá que ver qué más se explica sobre el uso (peyorativo o no) del término.

Comment: @blonfu, eso es lo que me llama la atención, que mucha gente lo usa como cariñoso cuando para otra gente es ofensivo. Como si le dijeras a alguien "cabroncete". Relacionado [Uso invertido de palabras cariñosas e insultos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4496/5481). Por eso quiero entender si el matiz de  qué es qué es un factor medianamente objetivo del lenguaje, cultural,  mera percepción del receptor o intención del emisor.

Comment: Yo, como @fedorqui, no  he oído llamar gorda a una embarazada a no ser que haya mucha confianza, donde incluso puedes decir: ¡Estas enorme! pero no se lo diría ni loco a alguien que no conozca mucho. Hablo del norte de España

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hablando por Argentina, la respuesta sería **no**, no es cortés ni habitual referirse a una mujer embarazada como *gorda*. Sólo se puede socialmente hablar de gordura con una mujer embarazada en términos que impliquen preocupación o apreciación de su estado, no usando el adjetivo directamente, en forma interrogativa, y con frecuencia sólo **después** de haber terminado el embarazo. El ejemplo más claro: nos encontramos con una amiga que está embarazada y la vemos demasiado gorda (o demasiado flaca) para la etapa de la gestación en la que está. Preguntamos entonces:

> *¿Cuánto engordaste hasta ahora?*

o mejor

> *¿Cuánto subiste de peso hasta ahora?*

O si tenemos más confianza:

> *Me parece que engordaste muy rápido, ¿qué dice el obstetra?*
>   *Subiste un montón de peso en el último mes.*
>   *¡Qué gorda que estás!* (← sólo entre íntimos y con tono de fiesta)

Como en otras partes *gordo/a* o *gordi* también se usan como apelativos entre amigos y en pareja, pero la referencia no es realmente al aspecto físico. (Se dice *flaco/a* también. A veces es difícil elegir.)

Answer (score 3):

En Colombia sí se le pude decir a una embarazada que está gorda/gordita.

Para embarazadas no usamos "grande" ya que aquí al referirse a adultos "estar grande" es estar *viejo*.

El peligro de usar "estas gorda" es en caso de que sea cierto y la razón NO sea un embarazo. Si a la mujer quien se llama gorda está en embarazo, no hay problema, pero si no lo está, quien la llamó gorda corre "serio peligro" ya que la expresión si es ofensiva en los demás casos.

Como tal comentario lo hace regularmente una persona de confianza o con alguna cercanía y con la certeza de que la mujer si está embarazada, lo usual es usar el diminutivo: *¡uy como estás de gordita!*

Comment: En Chile es idéntico, pero también usamos _guatona_ que es un chilenismo sinónimo de _gorda_.

Comment: En Chile hubo un comercial de TV de un yogur en el que se jugaba con la confusión que puede causar la palabra _gorda_, a propósito de lo que dices. Pero no lo he podido encontrar.